# How to use ASP.NET Core TagHelpers in dynamic data?

Tags: asp.net-core

We want to use TagHelpers to replace html elements (like links) in user content data (comments area of a page). The goal is to replace certain things (e.g. HTTP GET parameters).
The TagHelpers are obviously only called for static HTML, not for dynamic HTML from the ViewModel.

How can we use the TagHelper in dynamic Content?

We already tried the HtmlAgilityPack; it works, but it slows down the whole page build by a factor of 35.

Comment: This project might help: https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll take a look!